# Unless the input field is rendered this code does not work - not sure why?

Tags: inputfield

I have some VF code that looks like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="grey" layout="block">
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Flexible Pricing" columns="2" id="FlexPricing">             
    <apex:inputField value="{!offer.Annual_Forecast_Consumption_GJ__c}" 
                        id="AnnualForecastGasUsed" required="false" >
      <apex:actionSupport event="onmouseout"  action="{!setBandValue}" 
                    rerender="Band, DailyAverageUsed" status="counterStatus"/>
    </apex:inputField>
    <apex:outputField value="{!offer.Annual_Forecast_Consumption_GJ__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField id="DailyAverageUsed" value="{!offer.Daily_Average_Consumption_in_Units__c}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!offer.Daily_Average_Consumption_in_Units__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!offer.Gas_Consumption_Charge__c}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!offer.Gas_Consumption_Charge__c}" />
    <apex:inputField id="Band" value="{!offer.Consumption_Band__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!offer.Contract_start_year__c}" />  
    <apex:inputField value="{!offer.Current_calendar_year__c}" /> 
  </apex:pageBlockSection>             
</apex:outputPanel>
```

it basically shows a section that looks like this:

[image]

Now, the 3 bottom fields (Band & the 2 year fields) don't need to show, they just need to exist in the background. They are in the screenshot above for debugging purposes. The values they hold contribute to the lookup filter on the 'Gas Consumption Charge' field.

The screen shot is what is shown on creation of a new record of the Offer object.  The last 3 fields are calculated in the Apex code for this screen prior to the screen being shown. Here is an example of the 
the code for the 2 year fields:

```
 if (offer.Opportunity__c != null) {
      getPrimaryContact();
      if (Offer.id == null) {
          DeriveGasConsumption(id);
          offer.Current_Calendar_Year__c = System.Today().year();
          offer.Contract_Start_Year__c = offer.Contract_Start_Date__c.year();
        }    
  }
```

As can be seen the object fields are set to the desired values, here Calenedar year & contract start year.

As things are the lookup works perfectly however when i remove the bottom 3 fields from the screen, because they are not meant to be user input but calculated via Apex code (ie background fields) then the lookup does not work correctly. If i make the fields inputHidden on set a flag to not render them it still does not work.

I'm not sure what to do but I would rather not have to have those fields on the input screen in input mode or visible really.

Can anyone help please?

cheers
George

Comment: Since the last 3 fields are not meant for input, can you change them to <Apex:outputField> and then try hiding them. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't have an answer offhand, but wanted to confirm that I have experienced this as well. In order for a lookup filter to work, the field which is being used as criteria for the filter must be in the page. I do not remember if it works if you just hide the elements via CSS - might be worth a try. Throw `style="display: none;"` (or `visibility: hidden`) on the VF tag and see if it works properly?